# Changing the values on a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

What I want is when the user enters some text on an alert input to be shown as in the picture below on a php created array:
[What I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNBHz.png)

What I made so far is exactly this except it enters the value on the whole array like the picture below:
[What I have done already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiszC.png)

**My code with comment's explanation :**

*popUp.php*

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Two-dimensional Arrays</title>

<style>
td {height: 40px;}
table {width: 40%; border: 3px solid blue;}

table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;

}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- GETS FROM THE USER THE INPUT VALUE WHEN PRESSING THE BUTTON-->
<input action="" method="get" name="button" type="button" id="inputChar" onclick="Click();"value="CLICK HERE">  

<?php 
echo "<table border =\"1\" >";
 for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
  echo "<tr> \n";
  for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
     echo "<td id='inputChar'> </td> \n";
      }
        echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>

<script>
// A JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ACTIVATED WHEN CLICKING THE BUTTON WHERE THE USER INPUTS THE VALUE
function Click(){
 var Vvalue = prompt("Please input the value");
 window.location.href = "main.php?Vvalue=" + Vvalue;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.php*

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Two-dimensional Arrays</title>

<style>
td {height: 40px;}
table {width: 40%; border: 3px solid blue;}

table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;

}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
 
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<?php
$char = $_GET['Vvalue'];
// GETS THE JAVASCRIPT USER INPUT VALUE FROM popUp.php

echo "<table border =\"1\" >";
 for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
  echo "<tr> \n";
  for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) {
   echo "<td id='inputChar'> .$char.</td> \n";
      }
        echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how we can make this happen? ( TLDR: I want to display the user input on the odd rows of the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, easiest is if you simply add a conditional. So that the string is only echoed of the row number is actually odd:

```
<?php
$char = "tsa";

for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
  echo "<tr>\n";
  for ($col = 1; $col <= 10; $col++) {
    echo "<td id='inputChar'>" . (($row % 2 == 0) ? $char : "") . "</td>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```